# How to put correctly XmlAttribute to specific node in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to reproduce this xml structure:

```
...
<cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="RSD">5000</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
</cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
...
```

And it works when I have non-complex properties in the class `LegalMonetaryTotal`, but in order to put XmlAttribute `currencyId` I was forced to create instead of decimal field:

```
[XmlElement(Namespace = Constants.CbcNamespace)]
public decimal? LineExtensionAmount { get; set; }
```

I created:

```
[XmlType(Namespace = Constants.CbcNamespace)]
public class LineExtensionAmountDto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// LineExtensionAmount
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement(Namespace = Constants.CbcNamespace)]
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; } = 54545;

    /// <summary>
    /// CurrencyID
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("currencyID")]
    public string? CurrencyID { get; set; } = "RSD";
}
```

And I got wrong output:

```
<cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="RSD">
        <cbc:Amount>5000</cbc:Amount>
    </cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
</cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
```

As you can see, the xml attribute is on the correct spot, but I need to remove `Amount` node, and to present the value one level up in, like this:

```
<cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="RSD"> 1000 </cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
```

I tried to put `[XmlText]` but it can work together with `[XmlAttribute]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XmlText` attribute cannot be applied on nullable value types.
This is the class that will work:

```
[XmlType(Namespace = Constants.CbcNamespace)]
public class LineExtensionAmountDto
{
    [XmlText]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("currencyID")]
    public string? CurrencyID { get; set; }
}
```

See workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28110988/5045688